# System.NullReferenceException when saving bool to NSUserDefaults

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I got very interesting exception. On first look it's very simple ,but when I look stack trace of exception, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have property in PCL that saving value to `NSUserDefaults`. The code looks like

```
public class MainSettingsService : IMainSettingsService
{
        readonly ISettingsBaseService _settingsBaseService;

        public MainSettingsService(ISettingsBaseService settingsBaseService)
        {
            _settingsBaseService = settingsBaseService;
        }

        public bool NotificationEnabled
        {
            get { return _settingsBaseService.Get(true); }
            set { _settingsBaseService.Set(value); }
        }
}
```

`SettingsBaseService` class is very simple

```
    public class iOSSettingsBaseService : ISettingsBaseService
    {
        private const string NULL = "!NULL";
        private readonly NSUserDefaults _preferences;

        public iOSSettingsBaseService()
        {
            _preferences = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
        }

        public void Set<T>(T value, [CallerMemberNameAttribute] string key = "")
        {
            var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
            _preferences.SetString(str ?? NULL, key);
        }

        public T Get<T>(T defaultValue = default(T), [CallerMemberNameAttribute] string key = "")
        {
            var str = _preferences.StringForKey(key);
            if (str == NULL || string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            {
                return defaultValue;
            }
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(str);
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

Everything is straightforward , but sometimes in release I receive crash on hockeyapp with following stack trace

```
[String bzero_aligned_8(System.Byte* dest, System.Int32 len)]
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at System.String.bzero_aligned_8(byte* dest, int len)
at First.iOS.Services.iOSSettingsBaseService.Set<T>(T value, string key)
at First.Core.Services.Implementations.MainSettingsService.set_NotificationEnabled(bool value)
```

So now I really curious , how can be null reference in System.String ? Is it bug of Mono ? This exception triggered randomly and very rarely. Just catch on iPhone 4s and iPhone 5s. And I build just for two arch ARM64 and ARMv7.
Looking for any advices.

Comment: Are you using a IOC container to inject the dependencies?  Can you verify the bindings are correct?

Comment: As I had write previous, everything works correct. Yes, I'm using MvvmCross in box IOC. Everything register as singleton. The crash very very randomly

Comment: Try making `_preferences`  static. Btw there is no need to save the `NSUserDefaults` in a back field.

Comment: I can't understand how it help me a static _preferences. It always not null.